# FirstOrCreate making duplicates

Tags: laravel

In Laravel I'm running the following

```
          PlateOrder::firstOrCreate(
            ['internal_order' => $internalOrder],
            ['internal_order' => $internalOrder,
            'order_number' => $order->order_number, 'product' => $line_item->name,
             'img_url' => $plate->template, 'template' => 1,
             'order_date' => $fixedDate,
             'qty' => $line_item->quantity,
             'custom1' => $firstLineTrimmed,
             'custom2' => $secondLineTrimmed,
             'created_at' => $order->created_at,
             'r' => $plate->r, 'g' => $plate->g, 'b' => $plate->b,
             'spacing' => $plate->spacing, 'top' => $plate->top ]
          );
```

Using firstOrCreate the first parameter internal_order will check if it exists.  If it exists it'll update it if it doesn't it should create it.
However in my database it's causing it to write duplicates.

```
84826   142544  1425441HIGHMARK2    08-25-2020  HIGHMARK    VINYLS  NULL    NULL    Colorado Plate Hat - Flex Fit / L/XL (7 1/4" - 7 5/8") / Black FF   prt_Colorado.ai NULL    2   NULL    2020-08-25T05:47:14-07:00   1   0   77  41  38  86
84827   142544  1425441HIGHMARK2    08-25-2020  HIGHMARK    VINYLS  NULL    NULL    Colorado Plate Hat - Flex Fit / L/XL (7 1/4" - 7 5/8") / Black FF   prt_Colorado.ai NULL    2   NULL    2020-08-25T05:47:14-07:00   1   0   77  41  38  86
```

It creates an identical record except for the id.  Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Congratulations; you've experienced your first mysql race condition! To ensure 100% this doesn't happen, I'd add a unique key in the DB on `internal_order`

Comment: The unique key would be generated where on the php side? If so the key in this example '1425441HIGHMARK2" is unique.

Comment: `firstOrCreate` does not update. what is `$internalOrder` variable holds actually??

Comment: It holds a unique string "1425441HIGHMARK2" so first or create should check if it's there and if it finds it it what would it do?  @zahidhasanemon

Comment: it just returns the matching record..may be you are doing something wrong elsewhere

Comment: How if it's inserting duplicates? In what scenario would firstOrCreate insert duplicates? @zahidhasanemon

Comment: Also I don't need to update the order if it's there I just want to skip it @zahidhasanemon

Comment: jacob answered with quite a good explanation..as i said earlier, maybe you are doing something wrong elsewhere..your key generates on the spot..what do mean by that?? how are you creating that key??

Comment: If the key is unique and it's in the database.  How would firstorCreate create a duplicate?  That's what I'm saying isn't being answered @zahidhasanemon

Comment: are you sure it's creating the duplicate?? and your key is unique too?? i would suggest you double check your key and any relevant database insertion in your code

Comment: I'm not suggesting it I'm saying that's what's happening lol.  It creates a duplicates with the exact key.  No white spaces.  @zahidhasanemon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Derek Pollard, I dug into this and it indeed is a mysql race condition.
To fix this I ended up making `internal_order` column a unique id.  Any attempt to create a double will error out.

Here are some references to:
https://github.com/spatie/first-or-create-racing-condition-demo
https://gist.github.com/troatie/def0fba42fcfb70f873b7f033fbe255f

Answer (score 0):

If you want the record to be updated if it doesn't already exist you should use `updateOrCreate` as `firstOrCreate` will not update the existing record but rather will return it. As for it inserting the duplicate records, it must not be finding the record that has the same `internal_order` value. Is it possible that there is trailing or leading whitespace in the existing entry that is causing it not to be found? Also, there is no reason to repeat the `internal_order` values in the second array as it will use the values provided in the first array automagically.

```
PlateOrder::updateOrCreate(
        ['internal_order' => $internalOrder],
        [
         'order_number' => $order->order_number,
         'product' => $line_item->name,
         'img_url' => $plate->template, 
         'template' => 1,
         'order_date' => $fixedDate,
         'qty' => $line_item->quantity,
         'custom1' => $firstLineTrimmed,
         'custom2' => $secondLineTrimmed,
         'created_at' => $order->created_at,
         'r' => $plate->r, 
         'g' => $plate->g, 
         'b' => $plate->b,
         'spacing' => $plate->spacing,
         'top' => $plate->top ]
      );
```

Comment: There is no white space I checked that.  The internal_order is being generated on the spot so it's unique.

Comment: I also don't need to update the order that's why i was running first or create if it's there just skip and do nothing.

Comment: Can you try querying for the model manually to see if you can find it just by the internal order column like this `PlateOrder::whereInternalOrder($internalOrder)->first()`

Comment: Yes I did and it's the same internal order.I ran a query and it returned the duplicates.

Comment: The query I provided should only return the one record, when you tried it you only got one of the records back right? I just want to make sure we are on the same page here

Comment: Do you have time to continue this in chat?

Comment: The issue was mysql race condition.  https://gist.github.com/troatie/def0fba42fcfb70f873b7f033fbe255f and also here https://github.com/spatie/first-or-create-racing-condition-demo

Comment: [mpyw/laravel-retry-on-duplicate-key: Automatically retry non-atomic upsert operation when unique key constraints are violated.](https://github.com/mpyw/laravel-retry-on-duplicate-key)